# В каких файлах проекта находится информация что это maven проект

Tags: spring, maven

Есть проект на Spring. Если я клонирую его с GitHub, потом открываю в IDEA, то она понимает, что это maven проект, т.е. подсвечивает нужным цветом все папки проекта - java, resources и т.д. А если я просто скопирую исходные файлы проекта в другую директорию со всеми папками - то IDEA не воспринимает это как maven проект, а просто как набор папок.
Но на GitGub я не вижу ни каких других файлов, кроме исходников. А где тогда храниться вся эта информация о структуре проекта?
Т.е. какие файлы мне надо еще скопировать, чтобы IDE воссоздала всю структуру папок как в исходном проекте?

Comment: pom.xml и структуру папок скопировали? Это все что нужно

Comment: Можно и ссылку на интересующий проект приложить чтобы проще ответить было

Comment: Да, скопировал, но почему-то IDEA не воспринимает это как проект maven.

Comment: Дело в том, что ссылку я могу дать только на GitHub, но если я делаю клонирование с GitHub, то все хорошо. А вот если я все вручную копирую в другую папку только исходники, то так IDEA не воспринимает это как maven проект.

Comment: ссылку приложите

Comment: и скриншот с развернутой структурой нераспознанного проекта пришлите